# Looking for free dll to uml reverse engineering

Tags: c#, dll, uml

I am looking for simple "plug and play" dll to uml tool for over viewing the code design.
I have 3 dll's (1 c# WebProject that use 2 Class libraries) and I want to see it visually.

Is there any free or low cost tool that you know I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Reflector has a visualization plugin, but I've never used it and I'm not sure if .NET Reflector is even free any more.

It's downloadable from CodePlex though: http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/

**Edit:** [A better link](http://www.denismarkelov.com/p/assembly-visualizer.html)

Answer (score 5):

ASSUMING you already have Visual Studio.

Visual Studio has built-in tools that you can use for this purpose.

Simply create a class diagram by pressing Ctrl-Shift-A, selecting class diagram from the "Add New Item" dialogue".

[image: Add new item - Class diagram]

Then, open your Class View, open "Project References", select and expand the appropriate assembly and drag the classes contained therein onto your class diagram canvas.

[image]

Comment: If the `Class Diagram` option is not available you need to [Install the Class Designer component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2017).

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about class diagrams you can try [100% Reflective Class Diagram Creation Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoDiagrammer.aspx)

Comment: This has now been superseded by the [200% Reflective Class Diagram Creation Tool](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207280/200-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool)